# Simple rake task causes an exception. Not a Rails app

Tags: ruby, rake, rack, rake-task, rakefile

I have a Roda app where I have a file "tasks/rake" with a simple content:

```
namespace :db do
  task :test1 do
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

Running "rake -f tasks/main.rake" causes an exception:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default' (see --tasks)
/home/user123/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are telling Rake which file to run (with the `-f` option), but you aren't telling it which *task* to run, so by default it is looking for one marked as a default. You haven't marked anything as the default, so it doesn't know what to do and errors out with this message. You can run something like:

```
rake -f tasks/main.rake db:test1
```

to run that specific task, or alternatively mark it as the default task:

```
namespace :db do
  task :test1 do
    puts "hello"
  end
end

task :default => ['db:test1']
```

and run with

```
rake -f main.rake
```

Comment: works.  however, `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` is empty. how can I set it?